# Python & Sqlite: In sqlite table, I have an id, name, and point. I have a list of ids, I want to sort them by points

Tags: python, sqlite

**Making an example that looks similar to what I actually have.**

**Table I have in Sqlite database:**

```
id1 | A | 13
id2 | B | 24
id3 | C | 35
id4 | D | 32
id5 | E | 16
...
```

**List I will work with:**

`[id1, id3, id4, id5]`

I want to sort this list by points saved in the Sqlite database.

The list would look like this later:

`[id4, id2, id5, id1]`

This is basically what I want to do for now. I've thought of getting the ids and points of users, and making it into a dictionary in python, but I'm sure how to do that since I'm not experienced with SQLite.

I want to know if theres a way to actually contain the code within SQL queries through more advanced stuff, or if not, the best way I can do it for python.

If the dictionary is a good way to do it, please help me do it. (I've seen some people saying that I should use row factory and such, but idk what that is..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly do the sorting in the query itself.

Use the following algo:

1. Send a list of IDs to query
2. sort it in sql
3. return the id list back

Try this *(not tested but should work)*:

```
id_list = [id1, id3, id4, id5]

query="SELECT id FROM sqlitetable WHERE id in ({}) ORDER BY points DESC".format(','.join(['?']*len(id_list)))

cursor.execute(query, id_list)
```

Comment: i think it work! but just to be sure the order is small numbers to bigger numbers right?

Comment: If you want small to big then just remove the "desc". That makes it descending. "Order by points asc" will work. This makes it ascending

Comment: uh this is awkward.. but im not sure it actually works. turns out the test i ran was just by randomness. basically it im not sure if it resorts the list bc when i print the list, the order stays the same even if i change the points for them

Comment: Im fairly certain the "order by points" will work. Can confirm that the "points" column is numeric? Maybe it's varchar and they're not able to sort properly

Comment: my bad, i had a flaw in my other code. i commented too early sorry